# Prove projection is equal to combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v_1, v_2$ unit vectors and orthogonal. The plane P is defined by $P = \text{span } \{v_1, v_2\}$. Prove that for any $\overrightarrow{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we have $\text{proj}_{P}(x) = (x \cdot v_1)v_1 + (x \cdot v_2)v_2$

I got $\text{proj}_{P}(x) = \text{perp}_{P}(x) = x - \text{proj}_{n}(x) = x - \frac{\overrightarrow{x} \cdot \overrightarrow{n}}{||n||^2}\overrightarrow{n}$, where $x$ is the vector and $n$ is the normal vector for $P$.

How do I proceed now?

I know that:

$n \cdot \text{proj}_{P}(x) = 0$ , but that isnt helping.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$x=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+n\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  proj_P(x)=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2$$
for some constants $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and some vector $n$ which is perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v_2$.  Take the dot product of the first equation with $v_1$ and see what you get.

Good luck!

Comment: How can you claim $x = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + n$?

Comment: Because that's exactly what a projection means: $x$ is a vector in the plane (which is the projection) plus a vector perpendicular to the plane.